# Inverse trigonometric equation and finding value of given expression

Tags: trigonometry, inverse, inverse-function

If $\arctan(4) = 4 \arctan(x)$ then value of $x^5-7x^3+5x^2+2x+9870$ is?

I used $2\arctan(x) = \arctan(2x/1-x^2)$ twice for RHS of the equation which gave me $x^4+x^3-6x^2-x+1=0$ and I am clueless how to proceed after that.

Also I am not sure about using the formula I mentioned as its valid only when $|x|<1$.

Please help me in this regard

Comment: That restriction that $x $ has to be less than $1$ is not an issue. When you solve the equation numerically, the answer for $x$ is around 0.33. ( +1 for the question though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

From where you have left, use

$$x^5-7x^3+5x^2+2x=x(x^4+x^3-6x^2-x+1)-(x^4+x^3-6x^2-x+1)+1$$